# After installing a new GHC version, why does ghc --version still shows the old version?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I've finally installed ghc 7.8.2, but when I type ghc --version onto my Terminal it still says 7.6.3 why is this? I do not want 7.6.3 anymore?

Comment: You should ask this question on the Haskell IRC channel.

Comment: #haskell on Freenode.

Comment: What are the paths to h&c - hove you got two versions - How were they installed?

Answer (score 3):

The executables you'll normally run are actually just symlinks

> ~$ which ghc
>   /usr/local/bin/ghc
>   ~$ which ghc | xargs file
>   /usr/local/bin/ghc: symbolic link to `/usr/local/haskell/bin/ghc-7.8.2'

In your case, it's probably the old distro-installed 7.6.3 instead. Remove/rename that and put the correct ghc symlink in place (somewhere that's in you PATH, it needn't be `/usr/local/bin`), pointing to whereever you've installed the new GHC.

Comment: I'm confused. Typing: which ghc | xargs file into the Terminal yields: /usr/bin/ghc: POSIX shell script text executable

Comment: Fair enough, then either throw that script away or edit it. There'll be a line in there that refers to your old GHC install, change it! Before doing anything like that, you should check out you can actually execute the correct ghc binary, by explictly calling `/PATHTOYOURGHC/ghc-7.8.2`.

Comment: Sorry where do I find this script?

Comment: `which` just told you that!

Comment: It said /usr/bin/ghc but looking there with finder it's not there?!

Comment: Sorry just found it, should I delete it?

Comment: Yeah this is impossible why does everything associated with Haskell have to be so f*ing hard!

Comment: It's no harder than with any other compiled language, only there aren't as many fancy GUIs targeted at all kinds of consumer operating systems. — I wouldn't delete the script, rename it to `ghc-7.6.3` or as I said _edit_ it. You'll need superuser privileges of course.

Comment: It is worth noting that adjusting your PATH and redirections is just system administration and more about your platform than anything.  That said, in the past people would vent about how "hard" Haskell was when the first thing they did was compile GHC - I don't know of any end user who compiles gcc or cpython from source.  These days at least most people, you included, are grabbing a pre-built binary... but why?  Why are you not happy with the package available via a package manager?  Curiously, have you upgraded to GCC 4.9 too?